# set var mysql with start transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i don't familiar at database, That is my test syntax:

```
START TRANSACTION ;
SET @VAR = (SELECT `some ID` FROM `some table` ORDER BY `some ID` DESC LIMIT 1);
SELECT @VAR;
COMMIT;
SELECT @VAR;
```

i think is result is first select is null (because before commit) and second select is have value, and in my test first and second select have value, why? and how to fix my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem confused.  First, changes made within a transaction are visible within the same transaction.  Second, transactions are about changes to the *database*, not changes to the *session*.  After all, the database is ACID-compliant (or not), not the variables in a session.

The first `print` prints the value present during the transaction.  Changes within a transaction are visible -- in the transaction.  This is true for changes on tables, as well.  If you insert a row in a table and -- in the same transaction -- look for the row, then you will see it.

You should not see the row in *another* session.  You won't see it elsewhere, until the changes are committed.

Comment: yes, i want to get my last ID and manual increment, and how to fix it? @Gordon Linoff, because i have stack at this trouble...

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir . . . Ask another question, specifically about what you want to do.  In all likelihood, though, the answer is "use auto_increment".

Comment: i try to aks new question, thanks for help, i hope you checkout my question .